# Why does the Debug.Assert statement sometimes fail?

Tags: c#, .net

I write the below code, but sometimes Debug.Assert raise fail.
Why does the Debug.Assert statement sometimes fail and how can I fix it?

```
public class Warehouse
{
   private int stockCount = 0;

   public void DecrementStock ()
   {
      if ( stockCount > 0 )
         stockCount--;

      Debug.Assert ( stockCount >= 0 )
   }

   public void IncrementStock()
   {
      stockCount ++;
   }
}
```

Comment: I use this service to increase or decrease the count, and call by external service. Usually works fine, but sometimes raise fail.

Comment: The `Debug` class methods only work when the assembly being run was built in "debug" mode. Does your code "fail" when you're not running in debug mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really smells like a multi-threading issue.  I suggest placing a `lock` around access to the `stockCount` member.

```
public class Warehouse
{
    private int stockCount = 0;
    private object stockSynch = new object();

   public void DecrementStock ()
   {
       lock(stockSynch)
       {
          if ( stockCount > 0 )
            stockCount--;

          Debug.Assert ( stockCount >= 0 )
       }
    }

    public void IncrementStock()
    {
        lock(stockSynch)
        {
          stockCount ++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Say `stockCount` is `-1` when `DecrementStock` is called.  The if condition will cause `stockCount--` to be skipped, then `stockCount` will still be `-1` and trigger `Debug.Assert`.

If these are supposed to be the only functions that touch `stockCount`, then either

- `IncrementStock` is invoked so many times that the value overflows

or

- `DecrementStock` is called from multiple threads without synchronization

Based on your comment, I think unsynchronized access from multiple threads is indeed the problem.